# algorithmic puzzle for calculating the number of combinations of numbers sum to a fixed result

Tags: algorithm

This is a puzzle i think of since last night. I have come up with a solution but it's not efficient so I want to see if there is better idea.

The puzzle is this:

given positive integers N and T, you will need to have:

```
for i in [1, T], A[i] from { -1, 0, 1 }, such that SUM(A) == N

additionally, the prefix sum of A shall be [0, N], while when the prefix sum PSUM[A, t] == N, it's necessary to have for i in [t + 1, T], A[i] == 0

here prefix sum PSUM is defined to be: PSUM[A, t] = SUM(A[i] for i in [1, t])

the puzzle asks how many such A's exist given fixed N and T
```

for example, when `N = 2`, `T = 4`, following `A`s work:

```
1 1 0 0
1 -1 1 1
0 1 1 0
```

but following don't:

```
-1 1 1 1  # prefix sum -1
1 1 -1 1  # non-0 following a prefix sum == N
1 1 1 -1  # prefix sum > N
```

following python code can verify such rule, when given N as `expect` and an instance of A as `seq`(some people may feel easier reading code than reading literal description):

```
def verify(expect, seq):
    s = 0
    for j, i in enumerate(seq):
        s += i
        if s < 0:
            return False
        if s == expect:
            break
    else:
        return s == expect
    for k in range(j + 1, len(seq)):
        if seq[k] != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

I have coded up my solution, but it's too slow. Following is mine:

I decompose the problem into two parts, a part without `-1` in it(only `{0, 1}` and a part with `-1`.

so if `SOLVE(N, T)` is the correct answer, I define a function `SOLVE'(N, T, B)`, where a positive B allows me to extend prefix sum to be in the interval of `[-B, N]` instead of `[0, N]`

so in fact `SOLVE(N, T) == SOLVE'(N, T, 0)`.

so I soon realized the solution is actually:

1. have the prefix of A to be some valid `{0, 1}` combination with positive length `l`, and with `o` `1`s in it
2. at position `l + 1`, I start to add 1 or more `-1`s and use B to track the number. the maximum will be `B + o` or depend on the number of slots remaining in `A`, whichever is less.
3. recursively call `SOLVE'(N, T, B)`

in the previous `N = 2, T = 4` example, in one of the search case, I will do:

1. let the prefix of A be [1], then we have `A = [1, -, -, -]`.
2. start add `-1`. here i will add only one: `A = [1, -1, -, -]`.
3. recursive call `SOLVE'`, here i will call `SOLVE'(2, 2, 0)` to solve the last two spots. here it will return `[1, 1]` only. then one of the combinations yields `[1, -1, 1, 1]`.

but this algorithm is too slow.

I am wondering how can I optimize it or any different way to look at this problem that can boost the performance up?(I will just need the idea, not impl)

#### EDIT:

some sample will be:

```
T N RESOLVE(N, T)
3 2 3
4 2 7
5 2 15
6 2 31
7 2 63
8 2 127
9 2 255
10 2 511
11 2 1023
12 2 2047
13 2 4095
3 3 1
4 3 4
5 3 12
6 3 32
7 3 81
8 3 200
9 3 488
10 3 1184
11 3 2865
12 3 6924
13 3 16724
4 4 1
5 4 5
6 4 18
```

an exponential time solution will be following in general(in python):

```
import itertools
choices = [-1, 0, 1]
print len([l for l in itertools.product(*([choices] * t)) if verify(n, l)])
```

Comment: Can you give some test inputs and outputs, and say how long your current algorithm is taking on those?

Comment: @MarkDickinson updated with some sample output. my current impl takes seconds solving `SOLVE(10, 100)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I believe those inputs and outputs, though. For the first one (T = N = 3), isn't [1, 1, 1] the only solution? What are the two solutions I've missed?

Comment: @MarkDickinson I added N by one. now it's fixed.

Comment: Okay, those agree with my solutions (and I'm taking about 1ms for `solve(10, 100)`, with a result of `250639233987229485923025924628548154758061157`). I'll post my solution.

Comment: @MarkDickinson yep. your answer is correct. please show me your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observation: assuming that `n` is at least `1`, every solution to your stated problem ends in something of the form `[1, 0, ..., 0]`: i.e., a single `1` followed by zero or more `0`s. The portion of the solution prior to that point is a walk that lies entirely in `[0, n-1]`, starts at `0`, ends at `n-1`, and takes fewer than `t` steps.

Therefore you can reduce your original problem to a slightly simpler one, namely that of determining how many `t`-step walks there are in `[0, n]` that start at `0` and end at `n` (where each step can be `0`, `+1` or `-1`, as before).

The following code solves the simpler problem. It uses the `lru_cache` decorator to cache intermediate results; this is in the standard library in Python 3, or there's a [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578078-py26-and-py30-backport-of-python-33s-lru-cache/) you can download for Python 2.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def walks(k, n, t):
    """
    Return the number of length-t walks in [0, n]
    that start at 0 and end at k. Each step
    in the walk adds -1, 0 or 1 to the current total.

    Inputs should satisfy 0 <= k <= n and 0 <= t.
    """
    if t == 0:
        # If no steps allowed, we can only get to 0,
        # and then only in one way.
        return k == 0
    else:
        # Count the walks ending in 0.
        total = walks(k, n, t-1)
        if 0 < k:
            # ... plus the walks ending in 1.
            total += walks(k-1, n, t-1)
        if k < n:
            # ... plus the walks ending in -1.
            total += walks(k+1, n, t-1)
        return total
```

Now we can use this function to solve your problem.

```
def solve(n, t):
    """
    Find number of solutions to the original problem.
    """
    # All solutions stick at n once they get there.
    # Therefore it's enough to find all walks
    # that lie in [0, n-1] and take us to n-1 in
    # fewer than t steps.
    return sum(walks(n-1, n-1, i) for i in range(t))
```

Result and timings on my machine for `solve(10, 100)`:

```
In [1]: solve(10, 100)
Out[1]: 250639233987229485923025924628548154758061157

In [2]: %timeit solve(10, 100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 964 µs per loop
```

Comment: holy crap. that's fantastic. let me read your thought carefully.

Comment: Hmm.  That timing is bogus, since it's using cached results. Actual time on my machine is more like 0.002s.

Comment: it's ok to use cache. but what i don't understand is, even if you have cache, the cases of the longest walk over the whole interval will be `(n - 1) * (n - 1) * t = O(t * n ^ 2)`. this program seems to run faster than that. how would you explain that?

Comment: Note that for any particular `solve` call, the second argument (`n`) to the `walks` function doesn't vary. So it's only `(n-1) * t`, I think.